# ExpressionEngine top menu item linking to an external domain

Tags: menu, expressionengine

I'm an ExpressionEngine noobie, and I'm editing an existing website.

What I'm trying to do is to add my "store" item to the main top menu that would link to a third-level domain "store.mydomain.com". But all I'm allowed to do is link the menu item to some page on my second-level domain. Where should I be looking? Does this require a custom code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In EECMS things can be set up in multiple ways. A menu might be hard coded, built with an addon like Structure or Navee, or something completely custom.
My gut says you have some addon that is used for generating the menu. So it might be a configuration issue.
Some questions:

- what version of EE are you running?
- what addons do you have installed?
- can you paste the code from the template that generates the menu?